# Excel worksheet events won't fire on colleague's computer

Tags: excel, vba, events

I have a macro-enabled workbook that runs fine on my machine, but when my colleague tries to use it, the worksheet events won't fire.

I've done as much searching as I can and I'm still baffled.

The following conditions [all are causes/solutions in previous SO posts] are true:

- The events are named correctly (I didn't change the names) and are in the correct location (worksheet code) (as mentioned, everything works correctly on my machine, so these must be true)
- `Application.EnableEvents =  True` (I tested this in the Immediate window while testing on my colleague's machine)
- Security settings: 'Enable all macros' and 'Trust access to the VBA project object model' are both selected on my colleague's machine

I've put a `MsgBox` as the first line for each event handler.  These don't appear, that's how I know the event isn't firing.

If I launch a `MsgBox` from the Immediate window, it **does** appear.

Edit: We've tried re-launching Excel and rebooting the whole computer.  These did not help.

This is the code for each of the handlers, including the MsgBox test lines:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    MsgBox "worksheet activate"
    Me.Protect Password:=WORKSHEET_PASSWORD, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox "worksheet change"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    FermDataWorksheetChange Target
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I really hope someone can help me, as this is a business-critical application for my colleague.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried the code in a new workbook?

Comment: Or restarting the computer I've had office products get hung up with no visible processes running.

Comment: Hi @SJR, do you mean have I tried similar event handlers in a new workbook?  I have not, but I can if trying that will provide useful information.

Comment: Try running Excel in safe mode (hold down Ctrl while starting Excel) on the other computer, then try your workbook again. Does it work?

Comment: @Warcupine I'm going to edit my original post -- yes, we have restarted both Excel and the whole computer, to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried `Application.EnableEvents = True`? (I'm assuming this is what you meant by `Applciation.Events`...)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Worksheet\_Change Event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49641815/worksheet-change-event-not-firing)

Comment: And from the comments of one of those answers, you aren't trying something like running the file from an email attachment (rather than saving and then opening)? - *My thanks to all the comments and suggestions. We were able to find the problem. My associate at work was trying to run the file from outlook. When he actually saved the file to the computer and ran it in that manner, everything worked as planned.*

Comment: If you create a sub and call it from a worksheet button/shape, does that work?

Comment: Updates: I made a small test file with very simple event handlers, per SJR's comment.  That one worked on the other computer, so it seems the problem is rooted in the original file.  SamuelEverson, your link is one of the posts I read looking for a solution.  In our case, the file has been saved, so we are not running it from Outlook. (Also, I'm going to correct my typo.) @TimWilliams there is a button on another sheet in the workbook; its code runs fine when the button is clicked.

Comment: Also, @Rory, running in safe mode did not help.

Comment: Right-click on the file and select Properties  - is the file "blocked"?  https://superuser.com/questions/38476/this-file-came-from-another-computer-how-can-i-unblock-all-the-files-in-a

Comment: @TimWilliams the file is not blocked.

Comment: Long shot: does the workbook have conditional formatting in it that uses UDFs?

Comment: @Rory, there are conditional formats that "use a formula to decide which cells to format".  But the formulas use standard Excel functions, nothing user-defined.  Here is an example of one: ```=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(G7)), NOT(ISBLANK('alarm limits'!G21)), G7 < 'alarm limits'!G21)```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was likely to get Office and Windows current with the latest updates and patches.  That was the last thing we were testing -- however, the user's computer was so old that not all of the updates could be installed.  So they bought a new computer -- and the workbook runs fine on that.

Not a perfect answer but at least the problem doesn't exist anymore.